# Image tag in react and about router

Tags: image

## who con use image tag in react  and in which folder save images // src /public

What is the purpose of a router in a React application?
What is the role of the router in managing navigation and rendering components in a React application?

Comment: These are basic questions that could be answered with a Google search and are not appropriate for StackOverflow.